# Accessing and using images from the Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I have spent days researching this issue and I am getting nowhere at all. Things that have been accepted as correct by others are simply not working for me at all, and often the keywords they are using do not even exist.

All I am trying to do is ask the user to select an image from the gallery. I want to store this selection as a bitmap, convert the size of the image, and then save it to file.

They have the option to do the same thing using the camera, and this code works perfectly.  Not sure why the gallery is so difficult.  Here is my code (starting with the line below that won't add to the code block for some reason):

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            final Context context=this;
            Intent j=new Intent(context,PlayerSelection.class);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImage = selectedImageUri.getPath();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String fName = new File(getFilesDir(), selectedImage).getAbsolutePath();
            fName = fName + ".jpg";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
               Bitmap galleryTemp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),selectedImageUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Bitmap galleryPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(galleryTemp, 50, 50, false);
            //saveImageFile(galleryTemp);
            //startActivity(j);
        }
```

The sections that I have commented out above are where the app fails. When I get the path for the file, I am directed to **data\data\app.name\files\external\images\media\18630**,
 but the actual file exists in **Phone\DCIM\Camera**

I think this is where the issue lies, as when I then try to manipulate, or do anything at all with the image (Bitmap galleryTemp), the app crashes.

This is the method I use to call the above process:

case R.id.btnGallery:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            break;
```

Any ideas?  I have read practically everything that exists on this subject and nothing is working for me.

Comment: What does the stacktrace say when your app crashes ?

Comment: You have gotten a content provider path. Not a file system path. You can convert it to a file system path but you dont need it as you can change `Bitmap galleryTemp = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fName));` to `Bitmap galleryTemp = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageUri));`.

Comment: `String selectedImage = selectedImageUri.getPath();`. Look at that value. All what you do with getFilesDir() is nonsense.

Comment: @inmyth: I have no debugging of any kind. My emulator has no camera or gallery so I am testing directly on my phone. Have a feeling from the results i am getting that the bitmap is a null image, so trying to resize it crashes the app... it's just a guess though.

Comment: @greenapps: Thanks for your response.  Have already tried that, and have edited my code above to include the new changes.  It makes no difference to the result though, the app still crashes when I try to do anything at all with the bitmap.

Comment: Your code works for me. But of course i cannot test saveImage(). You start with constructing an Intent. That's confusing. Put that code down under just before startActivity. (For what doo you need that activity?). Also your code contains String fname which you don't use and getFilesdir() wich you dont use. So take it out.

Comment: If your app crases than the reason will be in the logcat. It's time that you post the logcat.

Comment: @greenapps:  I'd love to mate, how do I find that?  Also, I am not running the program in an emulator, as it has no camera or gallery.  I am building apk and running on my phone.   Will I still get a logcat for crashes?

Comment: @greenapps: Oh, saveImage just saves the bitmap to a file.   It works perfectly for the camera side of things, so I know this isn't the issue.  The app is also crashing before this step.

Comment: @greenapps:  The intent is so when the image is selected, we go back to a previous activity.   This is how I do it for the camera option.  Basically, there is an activity with imagebuttons.  You click on a blank image button and you get a new activity asking if you want to add image from gallery or camera. You make your choice, and choose your image and the intent sends you back to the activity with the imagebuttons, rather than leaving you on the activity asking you to choose between gallery or camera again.

Comment: If your phone is with usb cable connected to your pc and the Eclipse IDE installs and runs your app on the phone you get logs and errors and exceptions and all the stuff too. Just open the logcat view. Without logcat you cannot develop.

Comment: Before you use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(galleryTemp,...` you should check if `galleryTemp==null`.

Comment: @greenapps: I am running Android Studio.  I build the package into an apk and then up it to dropbox.  On my phone I launch the apk and install the app to test.  I will add the null test, but the app is crashing when I select an image... the issue is when I select an image it seems to be a null result regardless.  There is something I am missing here.

Comment: You can do all i said for Eclipse for Android Studio too. I dont understand that you are not doing that. Works way quicker.

Comment: @greenapps:  Not sure what you mean mate.   Have removed all the lines you said weren't required (they were for my debugging anyways) and removed the unrequired intent.   Still doesn't work.  I am at the point where I am thinking there is some issue with my compiler.

Comment: No. Start with developing in the right way first. Make use of the logcat: `If your phone is with usb cable connected to your pc and the Android Studio IDE installs and runs your app on the phone you get logs and errors and exceptions and all the stuff too. Just open the logcat view. Without logcat you cannot develop.`.

Comment: Add a new code block to this post to show the cleaned up code you have now.

Comment: @greenapps:  You are a genius my friend.   Got logcat working with my phone plugged in.  Issue relates to this snippet:  from pid=2618, uid=10325 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()      I am assuming here that this goes in the manifest somewheres.

Comment: @greenapps:  Figured out how to add permissions.  Was a single line in the manifest.... that's it..... works immediately.   All this time.  All these forum posts.  All these articles on example code for this task and not one mention of permissions anywhere at all..... and that's all I needed.  Thanks for your help man.  You are a genius.

Comment: For anyone reading this post, that is in the same boat as me and would like to stop tearing their hair out in frustration while they have some left, the working line is below.  Add it to the manifest.xml file:

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @greenapps: How do I accept your answer as the solution, it was only a comment.

Comment: You cant. But thats ok as you found the solution yourself. So congratulations and go on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code failed due to a permissions issue. For anyone else having this same problem, try adding this permissions line into your manifest.xml file:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="test.appname" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".Globals"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

You have to get path from the 'Media Store' content provider which gives you path to actual image, its thumbnail etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response mate.  In your onActivityResult method, you have selectedImagePath.  This is nothing to my compiler, should that be String selectedImagePath?  I have seen many others do this exact same thing, but it isn't a known variable.  I usually add String here, to fix it. But that is essentially exactly what my code already does. My code above says:  Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImage = selectedImageUri.getPath(); Same, yeah?

Comment: selectedImagePath is String as i might be declared globally my friend. As you can see getPath() function returns string so it is obviously string variable. And it is not same as you did.

Comment: Thanks for your response mate.    I will give this a try tonight using selectedImagePath as a global.

Comment: Have tried the above code using cursors and it still crashes the app. Am thinking maybe I have a compiler issue on my pc. Am getting a friend to test on his machine this afternoon.

Comment: put try catch block and use e.printStackTrace(); and post that error.